# Finding included or non-included points

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am writing for Python 3.5.2. I have a list named `coordinate_list`:

```
[
    ['x1', '120;40', '100;0;60;40'],
    ['x2', '200;50', '80;10;30;5'],
    ['x3', '150;15', '120;0;25;10'],
    ['x4', '240;60', '100;10;0;40'],
    ['x5', '260;45', '70;0;10;25'],
    ['x6', '225;15', '75;10;5;10'],
    ['x7', '273;20', '75;0;0;0'],
    ['x8', '221;5', '0;0;0;0'],
    ['x9', '345;20', '0;0;0;0'],
]
```

Firstly, I want to explain the meaning of the list elements. Each row in the list identifies a point. The first element, like

> "x1" , "x2" ," x3",...

is the name of the point. The next element is the point's coordinates, separated by `;`. The final element is the point's range. For example, x1's coordinates are (120, 40). And it reaches to (120 + 100) on the east, (120 - 0) on the west, (40 + 60) on the north, and (40 - 40) on the south.

If any other point is in this range, I must put it in a dictionary or a list. For instance, x1's range is (220, 120, 100, 0) (east, west, north, south) so x1 includes x2 and x3.

How can I do that? I wrote something but it is very unpythonic. I created lots of list, and it is not readable. Also, I got stuck finding the included possible points.

Comment: Start by writing a `Point` class with attributes such as `x_coord`, `y_coord`, `reach_west`, ...

Comment: @timgeb you mean that I can create three different list which includes the coordinates and range?

Comment: no, I mean that you should start by writing a `Point` class with attributes such as `x_coord`, `y_coord`, `reach_west`, ...  Then you can put instances of `Point` into a list. After that, augment your class with an `includes_other_point` method which solves the problem of overlapping rectangles.

Comment: @timgeb Your advise may be practice and logic but I don't know class. I haven't learn yet and if I use class, it will be problem for me :((

Comment: Your code as-is is unmaintainable und unreadable, you will spend less time learning about classes than trying to organize representations of points (rectangles, really) in nested lists.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (Can you find someone versed in English as well as in your own language to help you (&me…) with your English? (*Not* talking about spelling errors like `seperated` - those can (**and should**) be taken care of by a spelling checker.))

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more grammatical. I also changed `(40 + 40) on the south` to `(40 - 40) on the south` because that makes more sense to me. Please let me know if I messed anything up!

Answer (score 0):

As timgeb mentions, storing your data in a class makes it easier to develop and maintain your code than trying to do everything with lists.

Here is a simple class structure that does the job.

```
data = [
    ['x1', '120;40', '100;0;60;40'],
    ['x2', '200;50', '80;10;30;5'],
    ['x3', '150;15', '120;0;25;10'],
    ['x4', '240;60', '100;10;0;40'],
    ['x5', '260;45', '70;0;10;25'],
    ['x6', '225;15', '75;10;5;10'],
    ['x7', '273;20', '75;0;0;0'],
    ['x8', '221;5', '0;0;0;0'],
    ['x9', '345;20', '0;0;0;0'],
]

class Point:
    def __init__(self, name, xy, extent):
        ''' Extract the point's coordinates and compute its bounds ''' 
        self.name = name
        self.x, self.y = [int(u) for u in xy.split(';')]
        east, west, north, south = [int(u) for u in extent.split(';')]
        self.east = self.x + east
        self.west = self.x - west
        self.north = self.y + north
        self.south = self.y - south

    def __repr__(self):
        ''' Create a simple string representation of the Point '''
        fmt = "('{name}', ({x}, {y}), ({east}, {west}, {north}, {south}))"
        return fmt.format(**self.__dict__)

    def includes(self, other):
        ''' Test if `other` is in the bounds of `self` '''
        return (self.west <= other.x <= self.east and 
            self.south <= other.y <= self.north)

# Convert the original data to a list of Points
coords = [Point(*row) for row in data]
for p in coords:
    print(p)
print()

#Find which points p2 are in the bounds of each point p1
for p1 in coords:
    print(p1.name, [p2.name for p2 in coords if p2 != p1 and p1.includes(p2)])
```

**output**

```
('x1', (120, 40), (220, 120, 100, 0))
('x2', (200, 50), (280, 190, 80, 45))
('x3', (150, 15), (270, 150, 40, 5))
('x4', (240, 60), (340, 230, 60, 20))
('x5', (260, 45), (330, 260, 55, 20))
('x6', (225, 15), (300, 215, 20, 5))
('x7', (273, 20), (348, 273, 20, 20))
('x8', (221, 5), (221, 221, 5, 5))
('x9', (345, 20), (345, 345, 20, 20))

x1 ['x2', 'x3']
x2 ['x4', 'x5']
x3 ['x6', 'x8']
x4 ['x5', 'x7']
x5 ['x7']
x6 ['x7', 'x8']
x7 ['x9']
x8 []
x9 []
```

Comment: A fine answer, and you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear (understandable language difficulties) so apologies if I have misinterpreted the question.

I believe you wish to determine if each 'point' lays within the bounds of a rectangle around each other point.

To solve this we first create a class to represent each `Rectangle`:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, center_x, center_y, east, west, north, south):
        self._center_x = center_x
        self._center_y = center_y
        self._north = center_y + north
        self._south = center_y - south
        self._west = center_x - west
        self._east = center_x + east

    def containsPoint(self, other):
        return other._center_y <= self._north and other._center_y >= self._south and other._center_x >= self._west and other._center_x <= self._east

    def __repr__(self):
        return "center=({}, {}), east={}, west={}, north={}, south={}".format(self._center_x, self._center_y, self._east, self._west, self._north, self._south)
```

Each instance of this class stores the north, east, south & west values along with the center point coordinates.  The `containsPoint` function then determines whether the center of any given `Rectangle` is within the bounds of another `Rectangle`

Next we take the raw input data and do some simple parsing to get it into a more manageable form:

```
data = [['x1', '120;40', '100;0;60;40'], ['x2', '200;50', '80;10;30;5'], ['x3', '150;15', '120;0;25;10'],
        ['x4', '240;60', '100;10;0;40'], ['x5', '260;45', '70;0;10;25'], ['x6', '225;15', '75;10;5;10'],
        ['x7', '273;20', '75;0;0;0'], ['x8', '221;5', '0;0;0;0'], ['x9', '345;20', '0;0;0;0']]

coords = {}
for coord in data:
    name = coord[0]
    center_x, center_y = [int(n) for n in coord[1].split(';')]
    east, west, north, south = [int(n) for n in coord[2].split(';')]
    coords[name] = Rectangle(center_x, center_y, east, west, north, south)
```

So now we have a map of names (i.e. `x1`, `x2` and so on) to an instance of the `Rectangle` class.

Now we have this we can write a simple O(n^2) algorithm to compare each rectangle's center with every other rectangle:

```
for name1, coord1 in coords.iteritems():
    for name2, coord2 in coords.iteritems():
        if name1 == name2:
            continue
        print("testing if centre of {}({}) is in {}({}), result is {}".format(name1, coord1, name2, coord2, coord2.containsPoint(coord1)))
```

Produces the output:

```
testing if centre of x8(center=(221, 5), east=221, west=221, north=5, south=5) is in x9(center=(345, 20), east=345, west=345, north=20, south=20), result is False
testing if centre of x8(center=(221, 5), east=221, west=221, north=5, south=5) is in x2(center=(200, 50), east=280, west=190, north=80, south=45), result is False
testing if centre of x8(center=(221, 5), east=221, west=221, north=5, south=5) is in x3(center=(150, 15), east=270, west=150, north=40, south=5), result is True
testing if centre of x8(center=(221, 5), east=221, west=221, north=5, south=5) is in x1(center=(120, 40), east=220, west=120, north=100, south=0), result is False
... snip long output ...
```

I hope even if I've misinterpreted your requirement that this gives you enough of a clue to get you going.